# Pass variable to scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an element "stick" once it has been scrolled past (and unstick once it's been scrolled above).

This almost works however I'm having trouble setting the position of the element (called the `offset` in my code) from staying in its initial state.

I have attempted to set the offset at `window.ready` and then to do the calculation as to whether to make the element sticky or unsticky in `window.scroll` but I only get `[object Object]` when I try to pass the value, which should be an `int` to the `window.scroll` function

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRyKBY

Code:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
            var ele = $('.sidebar__ad');
            var window = $('body');
            var offset =  ele.offset().top-window.offset().top;
            console.log('Offset = ' + offset);
        });

    $(window).on('scroll', function(offset) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > offset) {
            ele.addClass('sidebar__ad--sticky');
        }

        console.log(scrollTop + ' & ' + offset);

        if (scrollTop < offset) {
            console.log(scrollTop + ' & ' + offset);
            ele.removeClass('sidebar__ad--sticky');
        }
    });
```

**How do I retain the initial `offset` as the value when the page loads, and then use it on `window.scroll`?**

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you could use [position: sticky;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) if your browser target supports it. Or you could include a [polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) for the browsers that do not support it natively.

Comment: I've never done this but maybe session storage or local storage?